# Implementing Hoare's algorithm for better performance on Quicksort and reading the amount of Comparisons & Swaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I have the following C++ code below on algorithms for sorting. I am in the process of making improvements to Quicksort applying Hoare's scheme. As part of the algorithm, I would like to see how many comparisons and swaps are made and I am currently struggling to have this algorithm working properly. When the algorithm is set to Quicksort and using either Random or Reverse as the dataset with elements of 100 000 the output I get is 'Oops'. Would it be possible to explain why this is happening and where I could make adjustments/improvements?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static long comparisons = 0;
static long swaps = 0;

void swap(int* a, int* b) {

    swaps++;
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int* first, int* last) {

    int n = last - first;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            comparisons++;
            if (first [j] < first [min_index]) {
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        comparisons++;
        if (min_index != i) {
            swap(first + i, first + min_index);
        }
    }
}

void insertionSort(int* first, int* last) {

    int n = last - first;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            comparisons++;
            if (first[j] < first [min_index]) {
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        comparisons++;
        if (min_index != i) {
            swap(first + i, first + min_index);
        }
    }
}

int partition(int low, int high) {

    int pivot = low;
    int i = low - 1;
    int j = high + 1;
    while (true) {

        do {
            i++;
            comparisons++;
        }
        while (i < pivot);

        do {
            j--;
            comparisons++;
        }
        while (j > pivot);

        if (i >= j) {
            return j;
        }

        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
        swaps++;

        swap(i, j);
    }
}

void quickSort(int low, int high) {

    if (low >= high) {
        return;
    }

    int pivot = partition(low, high);
    quickSort(low, pivot);
    quickSort(pivot + 1, high);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string algorithm = "quicksort";
    string dataset = "reverse";

    for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "ravgsin")) != -1;) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'r':
            dataset = "random";
            break;
        case 'a':
            dataset = "sorted";
            break;
        case 'v':
            dataset = "reverse";
            break;
        case 'q':
            algorithm = "quicksort";
            break;
        case 's':
            algorithm = "selection";
            break;
        case 'i':
            algorithm = "insertion";
            break;
        case 'n':
            algorithm = "none";
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    const int size = argc > 0 ? atoi(argv[0]) : 100000;
    int* data = new int[size];

    if (dataset == "sorted") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "reverse") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = size - i - 1;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "random") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = rand() % size;
        }
    }
    if (algorithm == "quicksort") {
        quickSort(*data, *(data + size));
    }
    else if (algorithm == "selection") {
        selectionSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm == "insertion") {
        insertionSort(data, data + size);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (data[i] < data[i - 1]) {
            cout << "Oops!" << '\n';
            exit(1);
        }
    }

cout << "OK" << '\n';
cout << "Algorithm:   " << algorithm << '\n';
cout << "Data set:    " << dataset << '\n';
cout << "Size:        " << size << '\n';
    //Uncomment for level 3 and 4
    cout << "Comparisons: " << comparisons << '\n';
    cout << "Swaps:       " << swaps << '\n';

    delete[] data;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is _the_ issue, but both of your comparison loops in `partition` seem flawed: you appear to be comparing index values where you should be comparing data values.

Comment: A [mre] would exclude all the unnecessary stuff (e.g., the other sort methods, command line parsing, etc). The emphasis is on _minimal_. Build the dataset, call quicksort, display results.

Comment: This is one of those cases where `using namespace std;` hides a problem from you.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to quicksort passes in data values, not indexes. It is equivalent to

```
quicksort(data[0], data[size]);
```

which, since data has `size` elements allocated to it, is an out-of-bounds access.

The call to quicksort needs to include the data to be sorted and the index values in that array to sort.

```
quicksort(data, 0, size - 1);
```

Appropriate changes need to be made to your quicksort function (which, currently, does nothing useful).

Comment: After reading all comments, I have got a mixed response. Although, I have understood that I need to pass the data values rather than indexes. My first question is my partition function correct? As for the quicksort function do I need to declare int data as a parameter along with int low and int high?